# Why can't turn off my win10 with power button on the front panel in my home computer main chassis?

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

I can turn off my win10 in the menu  `power--shut down`,it will never be turned on automatically.
[image]

The strange things happen when i press the power button on the front panel in my home computer main chassis，my pc will be turned off and then immediately automatically turned on !

I google searched some article ,still can't solved then!
The main setting in my win10.

[image: setting in my win10]

Comment: If you shut down Windows but the PC stays on with shut down OS then this can be a driver problem or a problem with your BIOS (especially the ACPI part). Make sure you have installed the latest BIOS for your mainboard.

Comment: In addition to updating BIOS as suggested, also run DISM /SFC to do initial repairs on Windows.  .....   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Try to run the Power troubleshooter. If that doesn't help, try the solutions in [this article](https://www.partitionwizard.com/clone-disk/win10-restarts-after-shutdown.html).